# Issue with GPU utilization with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, tf.keras

I am trying to train a network (a lrcn ie a CNN followed by LSTM) using TensoFlow like so:

```
model=Sequential();                          
..
.
.
# my model 

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                validation_data=validation_generator,
                use_multiprocessing=True,
                workers=6)
```

I am following [this link](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) to create the generator class. It looks like this:

```
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
# 'Generates data for Keras'
def __init__(self, list_ids, labels, batch_size = 8, dim = (15, 16, 3200), n_channels = 1,
             n_classes = 3, shuffle = True):
    # 'Initialization'
    self.dim = dim
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.labels = labels
    self.list_IDs = list_ids
    self.n_channels = n_channels
    self.n_classes = n_classes
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.on_epoch_end()

def __len__(self):
    # 'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
    return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

def __getitem__(self, index):
    # 'Generate one batch of data'
    # Generate indexes of the batch
    indexes = self.indexes[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * self.batch_size]

    # Find list of IDs
    list_ids_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

    # Generate data
    X, y = self.__data_generation(list_ids_temp)

    return X, y

def on_epoch_end(self):
    # Updates indexes after each epoch'
    self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
    if self.shuffle:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

def __data_generation(self, list_ids_temp):
    # 'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
    # Initialization
    X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
    y = np.empty(self.batch_size, dtype = int)

    sequences = np.empty((15, 16, 3200, self.n_channels))

    # Generate data
    for i, ID in enumerate(list_ids_temp):
        with h5py.File(ID) as file:
            _data = list(file['decimated_data'])

        _npData = np.array(_data)
        _allSequences = np.transpose(_npData)

        # a 16 x 48000 matrix is split into 15 sequences of size 16x3200
        for sq in range(15):
            sequences[sq, :, :, :] = np.reshape(_allSequences[0:16, i:i + 3200], (16, 3200, 1))
        # Store sample
        X[i, ] = sequences

        # Store class
        y[i] = self.labels[ID]

    return X, tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes = self.n_classes)
```

This works fine and the code runs, however, I notice that the GPU usage remains 0. When I set log_device_placement to true, it shows the operations being assigned to GPU. But when I monitor the GPU using the task manager or `nvidia-smi`, I see no activity.

But when I don't use the DataGenerator class and just use model.fit() using generated like this the one shown below, I notice that the program does use GPU.

```
data = np.random.random((550, num_seq, rows, cols, ch))    
label = np.random.random((num_of_samples,1))

_data['train'] = data[0:500,:]
_label['train'] = label[0:500, :]

_data['valid'] = data[500:,:]
_label['valid']=label[500:,:]

model.fit(data['train'],
                    labels['train'],
                    epochs = FLAGS.epochs,
                    batch_size = FLAGS.batch_size,
                    validation_data = (data['valid'], labels['valid']),
                    shuffle = True,
                    callbacks = [tb, early_stopper, checkpoint])'
```

So I'm guessing it can't be because my NVIDIA drivers were installed wrong or TensorFlow was installed incorrectly and this is the message I get when I run both the codes, which indicates TF can recognize my GPU[image] which leads me to believe there is something wrong with my `DataGenerator` class and/or the `fit_generator()`

Can anyone help me point out what I am doing wrong?

I am using TensorFlow 1.10 and cUDA 9 on a windows 10 machine with GTX 1050Ti.

Comment: I think the reason of the problem is that too much computation within `__data_generation` in `DataGenerator` leads to generate data is too slow. Your GPU has processed a batch data it requires more data. But if `DataGenerator` ever takes longer time than GPU, the GPU will stop and wait for the generator to yield new batch data.

Comment: @giser_yugang But the GPU would still train on the batch of images and I should be able to see it being used right?

Comment: Yes. But you have to catch up the refresh speed of GPU

Comment: Oh! Is there a solution for this other than reducing batch size or increasing the threads?cause neither of that worked.
Would processing the data and storing them as tfRecords and then reading those tfRecords in batches be quicker?

Comment: `tfRecords` and `tf.data.Dataset` are good choices.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help, appreciate it!

Comment: @a_rb: Can you please let us know if your problem is resolved by using `tfRecords` and `tf.data.Dataset`. Thanks!